# Replace href links with sentences python

Tags: python

I have extracted some information from different google alerts and my result of the extraction is something like this :

```
Facebook settles Oculus VR lawsuit with ZeniMax

TechCrunch

... founding and acquisition. “We're pleased to put this behind us and

continue building the future of VR,” a Facebook spokesperson told

TechCrunch.

<https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/12/facebook-settles-oculusvr-lawsuit-with-zenimax/&ct=ga&cd=CAEYBCoUMTA1NTQ0MzQxMTM3ODI5Mzk1MzIyGjBiMDY5NmI3NmJkMWUyMDQ6Y29tOmVuOlVT&usg=AFQjCNGxKHLqECQfjR0PA5dBJPecbuwB4A>



Duck.com now points to DuckDuckGo, not Google

TechCrunch

Non-tracking search engine, DuckDuckGo, is now a little easier to find

online after the company acquired the premium generic domain name ...

<https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/12/duck-com-now-points-to-duckduckgo-not-google/&ct=ga&cd=CAEYBSoUMTA1NTQ0MzQxMTM3ODI5Mzk1MzIyGjBiMDY5NmI3NmJkMWUyMDQ6Y29tOmVuOlVT&usg=AFQjCNFq8-XijHAo4VFK1ABU5lD2Kts3BQ>
```

As you can see I am getting links like:

```
<https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/12/facebook-settles-oculusvr-lawsuit-with-zenimax/&ct=ga&cd=CAEYBCoUMTA1NTQ0MzQxMTM3ODI5Mzk1MzIyGjBiMDY5NmI3NmJkMWUyMDQ6Y29tOmVuOlVT&usg=AFQjCNGxKHLqECQfjR0PA5dBJPecbuwB4A>
```

and relative text for this link is `Facebook settles Oculus VR lawsuit with ZeniMax`

I want my output as `"Facebook settles Oculus VR lawsuit with ZeniMax"` when on clicking on the line should redirect me to `<https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/12/facebook-settles-oculusvr-lawsuit-with-zenimax/&ct=ga&cd=CAEYBCoUMTA1NTQ0MzQxMTM3ODI5Mzk1MzIyGjBiMDY5NmI3NmJkMWUyMDQ6Y29tOmVuOlVT&usg=AFQjCNGxKHLqECQfjR0PA5dBJPecbuwB4A>`

In short my output for the input I have provided should be:

```
Facebook settles Oculus VR lawsuit with ZeniMax
Duck.com now points to DuckDuckGo, not Google
```

And this text should have all the relative links attached to it. In my output I don't want to display links, instead some text so that it is human readable. I am new to python so I am facing a tough time getting this.

Comment: Where are you expecting to be able to use this link? You need to extract the link first. Then format it as HTML and put that where the user can use it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have extracted link and the text and after that I have been searching different ways to get the output in the required format but no luck on that

Comment: You'll have to open the link, parse its html code for its `div class` `<article__title>` in order to pull out the title name and replace it in `<your link>`. Bear in mind that different websites will be parsed differently, as some might use `<title>` instead of Techcrunch's `<article__title>` I recommend using `requests` together with `defusedxml` or `selenium` or `scrapy` or `BeautifulSoup4` to parse

Comment: I am not doing any webcrawling. I have subscribed to some google alerts which sends me a mail with such links. I go through those mails and extract all the links. So I cannot use requests or scrapy.

Comment: Do you want to use `HTML`?

Comment: @stovfl what do you mean by html? Please elaborate

Comment: Like `<a href="https://www.wikipedia.org/">A link to Wikipedia!</a>` => [A link to Wikipedia!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#Elements)

Comment: I have done the same as of now